$ABACA = 0 \Longrightarrow BAC = 0$ if $A,B,C \ge 0$ are symmetric.
Problem.
$A, B, C$ are $n \times n$ symmetric positively semi-definite matrices. Prove that
$ABACA = 0 \Longrightarrow BAC = 0$ if $A,B,C \ge 0$ are symmetric.
My attemp (there's mistake in it).
We have $A B A C A = 0$. Put $x = A B A$. Then
$$ x^{\top} C x = (A B A)^{\top} C A B A = (A B A C A) B A = 0.$$
If follows from $x^{\top} C x = 0$ and $C \ge 0$ that $C x =0$. Indeed, there exists symmetric positively semi-definite matrix $\sqrt{C}$. We have $0 = x^{\top} C x = (\sqrt{C}x)^{\top}(\sqrt{C}x)$. It looks like (but may be no, because $x$ is not vector) $\sqrt{C}x = 0$  and hence $C x = \sqrt{C}(\sqrt{C}x) = 0$. Thus $Cx = C A B A = 0$.
Put $y = A C$. Then $y^{\top} B y = (A C)^{\top} B A C = (C A B A) C = 0$. It follows (if I was right above) from $y^{\top} B y = 0$ and $B \ge 0$ that $B y =0$, i.e. $B A C = 0$, q.e.d.
Additional information. I'm not sure that my attempt is close to truth, I want to find concise solution and anyway my attempt is far from being concise.

It's strange that you use the letter $x$ for $x = ABA$. But yes, for any matrix $M$ it holds that $M^TM = 0$ if and only if $M = 0$.

Note that for real matrices $M$, $M = 0$ if and only if $M^TM = 0$. More generally, for a positive semidefinite matrix $P$, it holds that $M^TPM = 0$ if and only if $\sqrt{P}M = 0$, which holds if and only if $PM = 0$.
With that, established, your proof is correct! Here's a way of reframing the same basic approach that you might like better.
$$
ABACA = 0 \implies\\
(ABACA)BA = 0 \implies\\
(ABA)^TC(ABA) = 0 \implies\\
C(ABA) = 0 \implies\\
(CABA)C = 0 \implies\\
(AC)^TB(AC) = 0 \implies\\
BAC = 0.
$$
I think the proof is pretty concise in this form.

Thank you very much! It's really concise.

Your solution looks essentially correct. Denote the inner product of two vectors $f,g$ by $\langle f,g \rangle.$
For any vector $f$ we have
$$ \langle C^{1/2}ABAf,C^{1/2}ABAf\rangle = \langle(ABACA)BAf,f\rangle =0 $$ so $C^{1/2}ABA=0$ and therefore $CABA=0.$
Hence, for any vector $g$ we have
$$ \langle B^{1/2}ACg,B^{1/2}ACg\rangle = \langle(CABA)Cg,g\rangle =0$$ so $B^{1/2}AC=0$ and therefore $BAC=0.$

Thank you very much!

This proof looks correct!
Indeed, for an matrix $M$, if $M^T M$, then for any vector $x$,
$$
\lVert Mx\rVert^2
= x^T M^T M x
= 0,
$$
from which any $Mx = 0$ and so $M = 0$.
In terms of a concise solution, I think that what you're referring to is that you're applying the same technique twice and re-explaining it, so it would be nice to have a unified result that you can just invoke.
One possible such result is as follows: let $X, Y, A$ be square matrices with $A, Y$ symmetric and non-negative definite such that $XAYA = 0$.
Then $YA X^T = 0$.
We show this according to your method, seeing that
$$
(Y^{1/2} A X^T)^T(Y^{1/2} A X^T)
= XAYAX^T
= 0,
$$
from which $YAX^T = Y^{1/2} \cdot Y^{1/2}AX^T = 0$.
But now, if $ABACA = 0$, then taking $X = AB, Y = C$, we have that $CABA = YAX^T = 0$.
Applying the result again with $X = C, Y = B$ finally yields $BAC = YAX^T = 0$.

Thank you very much!
